# Convert DEM to STL (3D Printer Format)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, dem, convert, 3d

I have a DEM in ArcGIS 10.1 that I would like to get into STL format for a 3D printer. Does anyone know some software that will allow me to make this conversion?

I have to use the STL format because that is the format required by my university's 3D printer.

Comment: Try this. It seems simple enough... http://adv-geo-research.blogspot.com/2013/10/converting-dems-to-stl-files-for-3d.html

Comment: Try www.DEMto3D.com, is a plugin for a free GIS software.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/229242/10229

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Global Mapper will be perfect solution for you. Please check [this](http://www.bluemarblegeo.com/products/global-mapper-formats-elevation.php#STL_Files) page for details and go through [STL commend](http://www.globalmapper.com/helpv5/Help_MenuBarAndToolBar.html#file_menu_export_stl) details also

<s>You can check [this](http://spatialnews.geocomm.com/community/boards/viewpost.php?cat_id=2&mess_id=5838) link also for second alternative (Some commercial tool is available)</s>

Comment: I am going to mark this as the best answer since it worked. Converting using Global Mapper was pretty dang easy. But, I wish there was a free/open source equivalent. Additionally, I was not able to print out the surface due to the printer being too small.

Comment: @jwx thanks for your reply. I will search open source software and let you know..thanks : )

Comment: the 2nd link has succumbed to bit rot, the domain name is/was "www.surfacemodeling.com", the tool "Import Points 2" and cost ~$100 in 2005. Likely completely dead now.