# Exporting stp files from QGIS with Mac

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to export terrain modelling data for 3D printing in **stp** format but can't find a plugin.

DEMto3D is an excellent plugin that does exactly what I need but only available in Windows.

1. Is there plugins for Mac that does the same thing?
2. Is there an alternative data export process?

Comment: Do you mean Stanford PLY format? If so might be a [duplicate of this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/228827/55203) which has some good answers. I don't think that plugin is limited to Windows, I'm sure I've used it on Linux before.

Comment: Thank you Steven, but... it is definitely a duplicate to the question you've highlighted but again it's Mac OS that appears to be the problem. DEMto3D and the tutorial from 3Dprinting both rely on Windows operating system.