# QGIS: Building heights and DTM to STL (or other format that CAD can read)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have downloaded a DTM and building heights from UK Digimaps (we have institutional access) and would like to:

Export them to STL or other CAD format. Is it possible to do this in QGIS or do I need multiple programs?

I haven't found any way of exporting to STL (dwg or other) yet.

[image]

Seems GlobalMapper is an option: http://www.bluemarblegeo.com/products/global-mapper-formats-elevation.php#STL_StereoLithography_Files
Isn't there a way in QGIS ?

Comment: It looks like this question is on its way to being closed as "too broad." Per this site's policy of one question per question, you should pick a single software you want to focus on.

Comment: I've reduced it now to just bare essentials. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is a carbon copy of that other question. More specifically, I'm asking about the Building Height layer, which is not covered in the answer there: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228827/generating-stl-3d-file-from-raster-aster-gdem-data

Answer (score 2):

You need to have all the information you want to export in a raster layer, and you can write the model in STL format with the DEMto3D plugin.

[image: demto3d-plugin]

Maybe needs some update, its GUI was a bit deformed. However, I was able to choose the size of the base, the height and the spacing.

[image: demto3d-gui]

I don't have specific software to visualize STL models, but freeCAD could import it.

[image: freecad-stl]

Comment: Thank you Gabriel. The buildings are a vector layer though....

Comment: @HCAI, you are welcome. I think you'll need to rasterize them.